# Swift: Error trying to get all of the desired values in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

I am trying to get all of the values from an NSArray. My NSArray looks like this (Obj C code).

```
NSArray *array = @[ @{@"title" : @"title 1", @"description" : @"description 1"},
@{@"title" : @"title 2", @"description" : @"description 2"}, 
@{@"title" : @"title 3", @"description" : @"description 3"} ];
```

I am trying to perform this with swift with the following

```
for  dic : NSDictionary in array {

}
```

However, this isn't working because of a strange error.

```
Type 'NSArray' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'NSDictionary'; did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
var array = [["title" : "title 1", "description" : "description 1"],
["title" : "title 2", "description" : "description 2"],
["title" : "title 3", "description" : "description 3"]]

 for dict in array
 {
    for (key, value) in dict {
    println(key,":",value)
    }
}
```

Comment: If array is an `NSArray` you will need to cast `dict` in the second `for` loop to `NSDictionary`, otherwise you will get error: type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'.

Comment: But if include NSArray in swift code am getting an error. So have implemented like that

Comment: Declare as `var array:NSArray = [["title" ...` and you'll see my point.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `NSArray` to `[NSDictionary]`. It will work.

```
for dict in (array as [NSDictionary]) {

}
```

I believe the reason for casting is because `for-in` syntax only works with `Generator`s. Since `NSArray` doesn't have it you need to cast it to the swift array.

Comment: `For-in` works with `NSArray`.  The casting is so that `dict` will have the type `NSDictionary`.  The way the OP did it, he was trying to assign an `AnyObject` from the `NSArray` to a variable of type `NSDictionary` which does not work.